# Action name in MVC same as corresponding http verb

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can action methods in MVC have the same name as the http verb? I know this is possible in Web API, but not sure in MVC.

For example, a post from a contact edit form automatically calls the second method in code below, and a get request automatically calls the first method.

```
[ActionName("GET")]
public ActionResult EditContact( int contactId )
{
  var contact = DB.RetrieveContact( contactId );
  return View(contact);
}

[ActionName("POST")]
public ActionResult EditContact( Contact contact )
{
  DB.SaveContact( contact );
  return View(contact);
}
```

**UPDATE 1**:

In MVC, one cannot rely on ActionName being set to a http verb for the correct method to be called on a post or get request, unlike in Web API. An explicit association needs to be created between the code in a view and the action to be called as shown in razor code at end of this post.

After trying this out in a sample MVC project, I found the above code would not automatically redirect a post request to the method named 'POST'. I had to either explicitly mention the action name as POST in the razor code for BeginForm or add an attribute of 'HttpPost' to the method for processing a post request.

So the following razor code would be needed to work with above code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Contact Example","GET","Contact", new {contactId = 235}, null)
@using (Html.BeginForm("POST", "Contact"))
{
  <input type="text" id="t1" name="Contact.ContactId" />
  <input type="text" id="t2" name="Contact.ContactName" />
  <input type="text" id="t3" name="Contact.ContactAge" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yepp, you just need to tag your post actions with [HttpPost]. The first will be the get method regardless if you leave off the [ActionName("GET")].

Comment: I was thinking that the action name would automatically cause the correct method to be called without adding any HttpVerb?

Comment: Please disregard my above comment. what you said was correct and I have explained how existing code could work with razor code.